# Regular Expression : User Name

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for a user name.

Here are the rules
1) At least 8 characters and at most 50 characters
2) Allows A-Z, a-z, numbers, and any other character except / character.

Thank you,
-Tesh

Comment: Any character except `/` based on what character set? US-ASCII, ISO 8859-1, Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\A[^/]{8,50}\Z
```

or, in C#:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\A[^/]{8,50}\Z");
```

The start-and-end-of-string anchors `\A` and `\Z` are necessary because otherwise `regexObj.IsMatch()` would return True even if only a part of the regex would match, and you want the string to match in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

`[^/]{8,50}`

If you want to be more specific about which characters you want to include then you can do something like this instead...

`[A-Za-z0-9,\.!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-_\+\=]{8,50}`

Comment: Inside character classes you only need to escape `\‍` and `]` (and depending on the position also `^` and `-`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Been testing it, when I type in something like james/33333333.  The regular expression returns true.  If I enter something like james/33fffff it returns false. Been testing against [^/]{8,50}.

Comment: @Hitesh Show some code and specify the language used. I imagine you want (need) to anchor the regex or otherwise have a small logic flaw.

Comment: I created the following function in C# (.NET)                  public static Boolean ValidateUserName(string user_name)
    {
    Regex objRegEmail = new Regex("[^/]{8,50}");
    return objRegEmail.IsMatch(user_name);
    }